# Buggy flip animation in Svelte

Tags: css, z-index, svelte, flip

I have a [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) app with a list whose items have the [built-in flip](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/animate) animation once they move. The items have a menu which is absolutely positioned inside of them and has a z-index of 10. The issue is: As soon as flip animation runs, the menu gets behind the other items. I have recreated this in the following REPL:

https://svelte.dev/repl/9d2f70193508421db3619a6d14bd3495?version=3.49.0

**Questions.**

- Why does this bug appear?
- How to fix this issue?
- Is there maybe a workaround?

I have already played around with `isolation: isolate`, other z-index values, select the task which is currently being moved, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Because the `transform` needed for the animation introduces a new stacking context and the menu is a part of it due to the hierarchy. The z-index will be relative to the new stacking context which only includes the item, hence the menu can never be on top of anything else.

> Fix?

Do not add the menu to the item. Move it high up in the hierarchy, e.g. directly into the `<body>`. You can re-parent elements e.g. using an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) (see suggestions in [this issue about `<body>` injection](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1133)).

Positioning will require a bit more effort. You can use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the relevant information for the target element.

> Workaround?

Maybe close all menus on animation? (And increase their speed.)